# Sharepoint page redirection using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

below I have some JavaScript which listens for mouse activity and starts a timer if there is no activity and then redirects the user to another page after say 2 minutes..The problem is that if I have this in a layout page it works fine but when I put it in the content editor part in sharepoint the timer works but the page does not redirect..Can someone please tell me what's wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mins, secs, TimerRunning, TimerID;
    TimerRunning = false;

    var activity;
    document.documentElement.onmousemove = function () {
        clearInterval(activity);
         activity = Init();
       // activity = setInterval(saySomething, 5000);
    }

    function Init() //call the Init function when u need to start the timer
    {
        mins = 2;
        secs = 0;
        StopTimer();
        StartTimer();
    }

    function StopTimer() {
        if (TimerRunning)
            clearTimeout(TimerID);
        TimerRunning = false;
    }

    function StartTimer() {
        TimerRunning = true;
        window.status = "if no activity is detected you will be logged out in " + Pad(mins) + ":" + Pad(secs);
        TimerID = self.setTimeout("StartTimer()", 1000);

        Check();

        if (mins == 0 && secs == 0)
            StopTimer();

        if (secs == 0) {
            mins--;
            secs = 60;
        }
        secs--;


    }

    function Check() {
        if (mins == 1 && secs == 0)

        // alert("You have only 2 minutes remaining");
        if (mins == 0 && secs == 0) {

            window.location = "Http://Test";

        }
    }

    function Pad(number) //pads the mins/secs with a 0 if its less than 10
    {
        if (number < 10)
            number = number;
        return number;
    }




    } </script>
```

Comment: try window.location.href? That always worked for me.

Comment: I replaced windows.location with windows.location.href but it is not working..the timer stops but it does not redirect

Comment: did you place an alert message inside the if loop and check whether the condition is being called, just before the window.location ?

Comment: Yea it wasn't getting inside..forgot to add Curly brackets after first if statement..its workig now....Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Can you help me with just one more issue..just 2 min before i redirect the user i want to show an alert box kind of thing which tells the user that session is expiring but also i want that the timer should not stop and still continue..If I use a alert box the timer stops and waits for the user input..is there some other way of doing it.

Comment: Try to show alert box using this way: `setTimeout(function(){alert("hi");}, 0);`

Comment: @DeepuNair post an answer here so steve can mark it as answered.

Comment: Is this question actually resolved? If so, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, although this is a trick, there is one more thing you can try. Well there is not activity on page for 2 minute, then **make the target page link visible on the page and trigger the click action on that link in the page**.

For this purpose you can have a look at jQuery [trigger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

Good to know that your issue is solved by adding curly brackets for your if loop.

I believe the setTimeout function commented by Kai would only fire the alert waiting for a particular interval specified. I think thats not what you are intending to do.

You can think about alerting the user before redirecting, by displaying a label text. The label text can be hidden using a div tag and be displayed just within your logic whenever required.

Good Luck Steve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");//opens in new tab
```

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)